# Why does Kara tell Dode to tell The Pin that Brendan killed Emily?

Tags: plot-explanation, brick

In the movie *Brick*, Kara manipulates Dode into telling The Pin that Emily was killed by Brendan. He does this because Dode loved Emily and Kara told him that she was carrying his baby. He wanted Brendan killed by Tug or The Pin.

What did Kara have to gain from doing this? Brendan accuses her of doing it for the money, but how?

Comment: I can tell it's a twisty plot from the title of your question alone.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: It *so* is, but it's also a really fun movie. Worth checking out.

Comment: Yeah, it's great. This one plot point is the only part that still mystifies me. I love noir movies - so complicated but in the end they all boil down to one person's dirty little secret. Real insight into human nature. Brick was so well done all around.

Answer (score 6):

Kara was Brendan's ex girlfriend and not the nicest person. She is a manipulator, and she and her group generally look to mistreat people.

In the film, she convinces Dode *to sell* the fact he saw Brendan over Emily's body to The Pin.

In the film, the money concept is largely glossed over, and it instead looks like it is being done simply because she is very, very spiteful.

However, in the [original novella](http://www.rcjohnso.com/brickscript/BrickNovella.pdf), it's clearly about the money (as even after Dode's death, she tries to blackmail Brendan):

> "I still know what Dode was selling, or have you forgotten? But I'd
>   play it smart. A 5 8 quick call from a payphone to copland and you're
>   through."
>   She came very close to me. Her robe fell open slightly.
>   "Five thousand. Cash. I know you can get it from the Pin, but even if
>   you can't I want it by first period tomorrow, or I play my hand and
>   bury you."

Comment: So in the novella, Dode owed Kara some money or something and she told him to sell the info to The Pin so she could get paid?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs: Not quite. If you use the link to go to the novella, the relevant section is on page 57. Brendan says to Kara: *You'd bury me at the same time, but it was mostly for the money. Dode thought I did it,
he like Em, that was enough for him, but he stuck to the money cause you had your claws in him,
cause he couldn't come away from the deal without it and make you happy*. In other words, Kara manipulated Dode into doing this, so she could get the money from him, given Dode was infatuated with her.